# Tool to create ppt templates?

Tags: libreoffice

I am very interested to learn creating templates for power point presentations. Could someone tell me if there is any other nice tool available for Ubuntu for creating high quality ppt templates? (other than LibreOffice).

Answer (score 1):

A quick look shows me that libreoffice can both save and open powerpoint template files, so I would assume that it is possible, and simply a case of doing what you'd do in powerpoint (editing the master,) and saving it accordingly.

I find 'ease' is a good tool for making higher quality presentations than libreoffice, but I can't confirm from here whether you can save them as powerpoint files.

http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/11/ease-clutter-presentation-app-linux-ubuntu/